# Performance test giving invalid results

Tags: javascript, performance, oop

Due to jsperf being down, I have a very simple perf test setup in order to assess how much faster using a constructor function is in comparison to using a factory style function.

Unfortunately, my results suggest that using the OOP approach (constructor version) is roughly (at least) 10 times slower.

Here are my two tests:

```
function stdFactorial(num)
{
    // If the number is less than 0, reject it.
    if (num < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    // If the number is 0, its factorial is 1.
    else if (num == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    var tmp = num;
    while (num-- > 2) {
        tmp *= num;
    }
    return tmp;
}

console.time("std factorial test");


for (var i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
    stdFactorial(20);
}

console.timeEnd("std factorial test");
```

And this time the same function except this time using the 'this' keyword

```
function oopFactorial(){
    this.doCalc = function(num){
              // If the number is less than 0, reject it.
        if (num < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        // If the number is 0, its factorial is 1.
        else if (num == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        var tmp = num;
        while (num-- > 2) {
            tmp *= num;
        }
        console.log('...')
        return tmp;
    }
};




var instance = new oopFactorial();

console.time("oop factorial test");

(function(){
    for (var i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        instance.doCalc(20);
    }
})();

console.timeEnd("oop factorial test");
```

Run http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/MwVNNR and http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/bdvXPK and check the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a console.log call that delays the execution in your doCalc method. Remove it and you will get different results

Comment: You the man! Thanks Leo. Now one final thing... i now get a diff of about 6ms with 10,000 runs of factorial in the favor of OOP. But the problem is once I increase the loop to run each function x 100,000 instead of x 10,000 the tables turn again. Codepen is updated to the no console.log and 100,000 runs however now the std fn call is back to being the winner by about 300 ms!

Comment: I've run your code in different scenarios (with a loop up to 100,000,000) and  in all those executions OOP approach executes faster ... BTW, why are you running the doCalc method inside a anonymous-auto-executable-function?

Comment: because I had both functions with the same var names in the same view loaded and even though the 1st would overwrite the last it bothered my OCD haha. Hmm weird about the perf, let me run more tests thanks again.

Comment: Confirmed... OOP is faster for this function regardless of how many times the example is executed.